# Should a single-row summary table have a primary key?

Tags: mysql, schema

Say you've got a summary table that's meant to have only one row (storing a row of statistics about another table). In this case I'm using InnoDB so that I can update it as well as the table it's meant to contain a summary of transactionally. Should I make this table have a primary key? If so, what, just a tinyint that's always equal to 1?

Comment: General idea: no, you dont need one, but be careful that you don't end up with two identical records.

Answer (score 3):

`InnoDB` will create a hidden primary key for you if you don't supply one.

It will sometimes be easier to have access to this key, as

```
INSERT
...
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
```

can be used to update this table regardless of does it already have values or not.

And yes, just use a constant `1`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should, you don't know whether in the future you could be using the same table for storing statistics for other tables, that seems a good place to store'em, then you will need to identify each row of the table.

Comment: You can always use ALTER TABLE to add new field.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to offer a devil's advocate answer, given that most other answers are "no you don't need one."

A primary key constraint assures that you don't get rows that have duplicate values in the column(s) you apply the constraint to.  You said you intend this table to have a single row, so why *wouldn't* you declare the constraint?  It could help prevent duplicates, which is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I would put an identity column on it (I don't know what the InnoDB equivalent is). It's harmless to do so and will make it much easier to select or delete a specific row if you ever need to.

Comment: in InnoDB it's an AUTO_INCREMENT column

Answer (score 0):

I never bother in cases like these.  The PK is used to differentiate from other records and in this case there are none.

Answer (score 0):

What if you plan to extend this table? It might make some sense to have a key defined. Again, it's just an opinion and not a necessity in your case.

Answer (score 0):

I would not introduce a PK at the moment. If you ever decide to use this table for other records as well, just refactor and add a new row (as you would probably need anyway) (Premature optimazation). There is yet one reason to add such a PK: if you use a framework that cannot update a record without having a PK that identifies the record.

Comment: Hah well it's not optimization.  Though I'm surprised there are no knee-jerk "every table needs a primary key!" responses.